# Git. Pull --rebase из удаленного репозитория. Что фактически происходит?

Tags: git

В интернете полно мануалов по `$ git pull --rebase`.

Например есть ветка `develop`, в какой-то момент от нее отбранчевывается `feature`. Со временем обе меняются, и если на `feature` выполнить `$ git pull --rebase develop`, то выполнится отмена изменений `feature` до момента бранчевания, далее обновится весь `develop`, и будет выполнена попытка накатить изменения обратно(Ну это все своими словами). Такая ситуация рассмотрена во многих манах и это все понятно.

Но что фактически произойдет если написать не `$ git pull --rebase develop`, а `$ git pull --rebase origin develop`? Мы ведь никогда не бранчевались от `origin develop`.

Вообще, стоит ли подливать изменения `develop` в свою ветку таким образом?

Comment: Почему не могли попробовать и узнать, что будет?

Comment: @Alex78191 Я попробовал и **что-то** произошло. Мой вопрос заключается в том, что именно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Информация: Для rebase локальных веток есть команда

```
git rebase develop
```

Определение момента разветвления истории коммитов идёт по индексам коммитов, так что проблем при выполнении команды `git pull --rebase origin develop` не будет.

Comment: Обычный `rebase` не рекомендует сама документация, в случае если `feature` уже запушена. То, что проблем не будет я понял, спасибо. Не получил ответ на вопрос, стоит ли так таскать изменения `develop` к себе?

Comment: @Oleg если с этой веткой работаете только вы, то проблем нет. Вы не писали в вопросе, что feature ветка запушена.